# How to clear cache for xds reference in visual studio

Tags: xml, xsd, visual-studio-2017

I have created a xsd schema that I want to host via a url.

```
<BuildInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.ops.spreadex.com/schemas/BuildInfo.xsd">
```

This seems to be working fine but when I update the file hosted @http://data.ops.spreadex.com/schemas/BuildInfo.xsd
the intellisense in visual studio is not updated.

I have tried restarting visual studio, but the cache seems to be persisted across the life time of vs.  Anyone know how to clear this cache?

Cheers

Comment: Did you try Build -> Clean Solution or Rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe there was an issue with the schema that was making me blame caching.  It seems that closing and opening the file in visual studio is enough to get the latest XSD.